# É má pratica não especificar NOT NULL em um campo SERIAL? Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, tabela-banco-de-dados

Olá, estava fazendo umas atividades e me diferi de uns colegas. O resultado final foi o mesmo, mas fiquei me perguntando se é má pratica utilizar o seguinte código

```sql
CREATE TABLE Estudio (
    codEst SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    nomeEst VARCHAR(25)
);
```

Em vez do que meus colegas utilizaram:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Estudio (
    codEst SERIAL NOT NULL,
    nomeEst VARCHAR(25),
    
    CONSTRAINT pk_est PRIMARY KEY(codEst)
);
```

O resultado, para mim, deu no mesmo. Li a documentação mas não achei nada acerca disso, nem em perguntas aqui no Stack.

Os dois são 'aceitáveis' e apenas estilo de escrita, ou devo me acostumar a utilizar a segunda, no sentido de isso poder causar problemas no futuro?

Obrigado!

P.S: as especificações desta tabela, eram essas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na teoria se está dizendo que um campo (ou combinação de campos de uma mesma tabela) é chave primária então estão implícitos o NOT NULL e o UNIQUE, e assim eu acho que nem precisaria explicitar o NOT NULL na declaração.

Inclusive pelo que diz [aqui](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-serial/) (vale a pena visitar para mais informações) declarar o campo como SERIAL também implica em NOT NULL.

Penso então que é só questão de estilo escolher de qual forma prefere declarar a PRIMARY KEY, e também não vejo por que explicitar esse NOT NULL na declaração do campo.

O segundo caso faria mais sentido se a chave primária fosse composta por mais de um campo. Para mim a sua declaração fica mais legível que a dos seus colegas.

E o nome do estúdio a meu ver deveria ser declarado NOT NULL, mas vai depender da regra de negócio.

Na prática é certamente bem comum e apropriado combinar SERIAL e PRIMARY KEY, pois ambos se complementam na hora de gerar uma identidade artificial baseada numa sequência numérica automaticamente gerada e já indexada para os registros da tabela, necessidade habitual em bancos de dados relacionais.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. Também me dei de cara com esse site, mas fiquei meio 'assim' porquê foi o único lugar que citava isto. Aproveitando, a forma de declarar as PK, no postgresql, sempre segue o padrão tabela_nomecampo_tipochave. Seria mais adequado utilizar um constraint, assim como meus colegas, e declarar como tipochave_tabela_nomecampo? Fiquei imaginando de usando este outro formato, em um banco de dados maior seria mais fácil de identificar FKs e PKs. O que você acha? Obrigado, mais uma vez.

Comment: Confie no manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Comment: @AlecsanderCamilo vou deixar isso para outros darem um parecer, não tenho uma opinião formada.